# Performance API on IE results are different values for each call

Tags: javascript, node.js, internet-explorer, performance-testing, puppeteer

I am trying to get performance stats in IE using puppeteer but after reading the APIs but still not clear why the results from the two calls are so different. Would I be wrong to say that the values for 'domComplete' and 'requestStart' etc should be the same across the apis ? I am not sure what values to take for performance testing of page load.

```
  const getEntriesByTypeNav = JSON.parse(
          await page.evaluate(() => JSON.stringify(window.performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")))
    )[0];

  getEntriesByTypeNav [
  {
    connectEnd: 0.8755,
    connectStart: 0.8755,
    domComplete: 1540.0755,
    domContentLoadedEventEnd: 1508.6755,
    domContentLoadedEventStart: 1246.9755,
    domInteractive: 1246.4755,
    domLoading: 25.9755,
    domainLookupEnd: 0.8755,
    domainLookupStart: 0.8755,
    fetchStart: 0.8755,
    loadEventEnd: 1576.0755,
    loadEventStart: 1546.2755,
    navigationStart: 0,
    redirectCount: 0,
    redirectEnd: 0,
    redirectStart: 0,
    requestStart: 25.5755,
    responseEnd: 63.8755,
    responseStart: 25.9755,
    type: 'navigate',
    unloadEventEnd: 0,
    unloadEventStart: 0,
    duration: 1576.0755,
    entryType: 'navigation',
    name: 'document',
    startTime: 0
  }
]

 const performanceTiming = JSON.parse(
            await page.evaluate(() => JSON.stringify(window.performance.timing))
        );

performanceTiming {
  timing: {
    navigationStart: 1583252459926,
    unloadEventStart: 0,
    unloadEventEnd: 0,
    redirectStart: 0,
    redirectEnd: 0,
    fetchStart: 1583252459926,
    domainLookupStart: 1583252459926,
    domainLookupEnd: 1583252459926,
    connectStart: 1583252459926,
    connectEnd: 1583252459926,
    requestStart: 1583252459951,
    responseStart: 1583252459951,
    responseEnd: 1583252459989,
    domLoading: 1583252459951,
    domInteractive: 1583252461172,
    domContentLoadedEventStart: 1583252461172,
    domContentLoadedEventEnd: 1583252461434,
    domComplete: 1583252461466,
    loadEventStart: 1583252461472,
    loadEventEnd: 1583252461502,
    msFirstPaint: 1583252460688
  }
```

Comment: Let's say, that the most of the time your computer does something else than loads and renders your page on a browser, and the performance results depend on what other tasks the CPU is executing.

Comment: Also worth mentioning: which version of IE are you using?

Comment: @Teemu the OP is finding that the results vary by about 50 years, though, not a few milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

The reason there are such differences is that in the first instance, `startTime` is 0 milliseconds and all other events are the number of milliseconds since `startTime`.  In the second instance, the values are milliseconds since midnight on 1/1/70, UTC (and are expressed as whole numbers unlike in the first instance, suggesting that the second instance is a polyfill; just a hunch).  To complicate things, in the second instance there is no `startTime`, and unpopulated properties like `redirectStart` have the value `0` - inaccurate and misleading.

So, compare apples to apples.  E.g. to determine how long it takes for `window.load` to fire, in both cases subtract `navigationStart` from `loadEventEnd`.  Results:

- First instance: 1576.0755 - 0 = **1576.0755**
- Second instance: 1583252461502 - 1583252459926 = **1576**

Same number! One rounded, one not.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Also - the Performance API is a fantastic resource (underappreciated and underused in my opinion), but some browsers only support it partially (MDN's compatibility charts, e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming bottom of page, are usually accurate).  So depending on how you're generating your web-friendly ES5, the "missing" parts may be polyfilled, or not, and/or you may be doing your own polyfilling.  For example, the fact that in your second example all numbers are rounded to the nearest whole number tells me that maybe a polyfill is in use - since the performance API bases its timings off of `performance.now()`, which returns high-precision timestamp, not just whole milliseconds.  Also, note that the lack of support isn't limited to IE - often Safari (macOS and iOS) is very, very slow to implement Performance API features: annoying, especially since ALL iOS browsers, under the hood, are Safari (that is, Performance API implementation is spotty not just on Safari for iOS but also for Chrome, Firefox, and whatever other browsers are available on iOS).