# How to get the timestamp of the DOM loaded?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

The obvious answer was using `performance.timing`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098117/get-the-timestamp-of-loaded-page), but it is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceTiming).

The [new interface](https://w3c.github.io/navigation-timing/#sec-navigation-timing) seems to give [only durations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60512728/performance-api-on-ie-results-are-different-values-for-each-call), but I can not see any reference of timestamp.

Example (from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Navigation_and_resource_timings)):

```
performance.getEntriesByType('navigation').forEach((navigation) => 
{
  console.dir(navigation);
});
```

gives

```
{
    "name": "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Navigation_and_resource_timings",
    "entryType": "navigation",
    "startTime": 0,
    "duration": 381.90000009536743,
    "initiatorType": "navigation",
    "nextHopProtocol": "h2",
    "workerStart": 0,
    "redirectStart": 0,
    "redirectEnd": 0,
    "fetchStart": 9,
    "domainLookupStart": 9,
    "domainLookupEnd": 9,
    "connectStart": 9,
    "connectEnd": 9,
    "secureConnectionStart": 9,
    "requestStart": 15.400000095367432,
    "responseStart": 49.40000009536743,
    "responseEnd": 52,
    "transferSize": 16819,
    "encodedBodySize": 16519,
    "decodedBodySize": 104257,
    "serverTiming": [],
    "workerTiming": [],
    "unloadEventStart": 0,
    "unloadEventEnd": 0,
    "domInteractive": 271.90000009536743,
    "domContentLoadedEventStart": 324.2000000476837,
    "domContentLoadedEventEnd": 324.2000000476837,
    "domComplete": 381.7000000476837,
    "loadEventStart": 381.90000009536743,
    "loadEventEnd": 381.90000009536743,
    "type": "navigate",
    "redirectCount": 0
}
```

Besides the documentation or implementation is way more complex.
How do we get now the *timestamp* of the page loaded (or of startTime) ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, not by google (which gives all answers based on performance.timing), but looking all the values of performance object.

I found this:

```
Performance.timeOrigin
```

Described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/timeOrigin)